# as3 regular expression to validate a password

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have a form that asks for a password and I want to validate if the password has at least eight characters, and of these eight characters at least two must be numbers and two must be letters in any order. I'm trying with this:

```
    function validatePassword():void
    {
            var passVal:String = pass.text;
            if(validPass(passVal))
            {
                 trace("Password Ok");
                 sendForm();
            }
            else
            {
                 trace("You have entered an invalid password");
            }
            function validPass(passVal:String):Boolean{
                 var pw:RegExp = /^?=.{8,}[A-Za-z]{2,}[0-9]{2,}/;
                 return(pw.test(passVal));
            } 
     }
```

But it doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: simply the regex **pattern** isn't correct ; )

Comment: Before asking, please do a search for _JavaScript Password Validation_ (AS3 uses JS syntax). This question gets asked a LOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this pattern `^(?=.{8})(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[A-Za-z]){2}).*$`

- `^` anchor
- `(?=.{8})` look ahead for at least 8 characters
- `(?=(.*\d){2})` look ahead for at least 2 digits in any order
- `(?=(.*[A-Za-z]){2})` look ahead for at least 2 letters in any order
- `.*$` catch everything to the end if passed previous conditions

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your regex is forcing the numbers to follow the letters (`[A-Za-z]{2,}[0-9]{2,}`). While it is possible to write such a regex, I suggest using a simple length check and two regexes:

```
        function validPass(passVal:String):Boolean{
             if (passVal.length < 8)
                 return False;

             var letterRegex:RegExp = /^.*?[A-Za-z].*?[A-Za-z].*?$/;
             var numberRegex:RegExp = /^.*?\d.*?\d.*?$/;
             return letterRegex.test(passVal) && numberRegex.test(passVal);
        }
```